# How to detect the wordpress admin bar in javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, navbar, admin, detection

I am using a navbar that hides when scrolling down the pages, and showing up when scrolling up in Wordpress.

The typical problem is that the WP admin bar gets on top of the navbar.

As my navbar srcoll hiding code is made in javascript, I cannot use the css code that I used before to add a space on the top of the navbar when the admin bar is present :

```
body.admin-bar #navbar-section {
  top: 32px;
}
```

So I would like to know how I can detect the presence of the WP admin bar in javascript so that I can add the space on top using the following code :

```
    if adminbar present then
document.getElementById("navbar-section").style.top = "32px";
    else
document.getElementById("navbar-section").style.top = "0px";
```

Thanks a lot as I have been struggling for a long while now... :} !

Comment: have a look at the z-index of the wordpress admin bar. it should lay over the rest of the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin toolbar has an ID of "wpadminbar". So your code just needs to reference this:

```
const $wpadminbar = document.getElementById('wpadminbar');
const $navbar_section = document.getElementById('navbar-section');
if ($wpadminbar){
     $navbar_section.style.top = "32px";
} else {
     $navbar_section.style.top = "0px";
}
```

You can also use Node.contains:

```
const $wpadminbar = document.getElementById('wpadminbar');
const $navbar_section = document.getElementById('navbar-section');
if (document.body.contains($wpadminbar)){
     $navbar_section.style.top = "32px";
} else {
     $navbar_section.style.top = "0px";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tokant :D !!

Answer (score 0):

For information, I also found this solution to check whether a given html tag contains a given class:

```
if (document.body.classList.contains('admin-bar')) { 
      document.getElementById("navbar-section").style.top = "32px";
} else {
    document.getElementById("navbar-section").style.top = "0px";
}
```